# sending hex value over for ZRANGEBYLEX

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am using c# 4.5, with StackExchange.Redis version 1.0.316.0. 
I need to send follwoing command to reids server to search for all my sorted set that start with aar.

```
ZRANGEBYLEX IWU [aar "[aar\xff" LIMIT 1 10
```

in my c# code i tried

```
querystring="aar";
 SortedSetRangeByValue("IWU", querystring, querystring + "\xff",
               0, 10);
```

When i monitor on redis server i see that it did not send what i expected, it sent this instead.

```
"ZRANGEBYLEX" "IWU" "[aar" "[aar\xc3\xbf" "LIMIT" "0" "10"
```

**How can i fix my c# code to send right hex values over?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply using  querystring + @"xff" worked for me.